# Discord Bot Command not posting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've coded a discord bot, when I use the command there are no errors in the console but it doesn't post anything in the channel. The bot has the correct permissions as most other commands work.

Code in question:

```
@bot.command()
async def plugins(ctx, *args):



    arg = list(map(lambda a: a.upper(), args))
    print(arg)
    if arg == 'LIST':
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.set_author(name='Chicken Bot', icon_url=image_url)
        embed.add_field(name='Plugins List', value= '**Server 1**\n Admin Toolbox\n Common Utilities\n PFE\n Chopper Drop\n UAFK\n \n **Server 2**\n Admin Toolbox\n Common Utilities\n PFE\n Chopper Drop\n Ultimate AFK\n Buddy\n SCP Swap\n Tranq Gun\n Stalky 106\n Better 939\n SCP 575\n Better Sinkholes\n \n Do c!plugins (Plugin Name) for more info!')
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

The result from the `print(arg)` is `['LIST']` in the console.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making `arg` a list with this line:

```
arg = list(map(lambda a: a.upper(), args))
```

Therefore `['LIST'] != 'LIST'` and the if statement does not run. You need to change your if statement to check if `arg[0] == 'LIST'` or `'LIST' in arg` or something along those lines. However you intend the code to run.